# Replace multiple domains in post content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have an array with domains I want to replace inside post content in Wordpress. My function is simple using preg_replace.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content' );

function filter_the_content( $content ) {
  $domains = array('domain1.com/out/','domain2.com/out/');
  if ( is_single() ) {
      $content = preg_replace("/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?(".implode('|', $domains)
."?([a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,5}.)?(\/out)?\/.+/i", 'https://domain3.com/out', $content);
  }
  return $content;
}
?>
```

After applying the filter, my content disappears and I have no idea how to get it work, replacing the domains in the array.

Comment: What do you want to replace the domains with?

Comment: with a third domain, lets say domain3.com. As stated in preg_replace line

Comment: Ok, what does `is_single()` do?

Comment: Also, is preg_replace necessary?

Comment: `is_single()` is a wordpress function that detects if you are viewing a post or page. Could be another function like a preg_replace_callback. I just can't find the right regex to do that.

Comment: Ok, are all these domains `http`?

Comment: Also, if `domain3.com/out` is the answer for each domain, then just return it as is? Can you give a more precise input-output example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex you have twice the extension and `/out/`.

You can solve this  with:

```php
$content = 'blah https://domain1.com/out/ blah https://domain2.com/out/ blah https://domainXXX.com/out/ blah';
$domains = array('domain1.com/out/','domain2.com/out/');
$content = preg_replace("~(?:https?://www)?(?:".implode('|', $domains).")~i", 'https://domain3.com/out', $content);
echo $content;
```

**Output:**

```
blah https://https://domain3.com/out blah https://https://domain3.com/out blah https://domainXXX.com/out/ blah
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/z8G2Oc/1)